# Chrome not showing as retina on mountain lion

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have a recently purchased rMBP. The Google Chrome browser is displaying as retina when launched from the image it comes packaged in, but when I move the executable to my applications directory it becomes pixelated. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you have an older version of Chrome installed before this version?